# va_arg with pointers

Tags: c, linked-list, c99, variadic-functions

I want to initialize a linked list with pointer arguments like so:

```
/* 
 * Initialize a linked list using variadic arguments
 * Returns the number of structures initialized
 */
int init_structures(struct structure *first, ...) 
{
    struct structure *s;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, first);

    for (s = first; s != NULL; s = va_arg(va, (struct structure *))) {
        if ((s = malloc(sizeof(struct structure))) == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        count++;
    }

    va_end(va);

    return count;
}
```

The problem is that clang errors `type name requires a specifier or qualifier` at `va_arg(va, (struct structure *))`, and says that the type specifier defaults to int. It also notes instantiated form at `(struct structure *)` and `struct structure *`. This, what seems to be getting assigned to `s` is `int (struct structure *)`.

It compiles fine when parentheses are removed from `(struct structure *)`, but the structures that are supposed to be initialized are inaccessible.

Why is `int` assumed when parentheses are around the type argument passed to va_arg? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`va_arg` is a macro on many systems, and evidently the parentheses around `struct structure *` causes the macro to expand so something unparseable. So don't do that.

This has nothing to do with the reason that your initialized structures are "inaccessible". You are allocating structures and assigning them to `s`, but `s` is a local variable. You can't affect a value in the caller by assigning to a local variable. To accomplish what you want to do, the caller needs to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer, which you can then initialize

```
int init_structures(struct structure **first, ...) 
{
    struct structure **s;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, first);

    for (s = first; s != NULL; s = va_arg(va, struct structure **)) {
        if ((*s = malloc(sizeof(struct structure))) == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        count++;
    }

    va_end(va);

    return count;
}
```

And the caller should do:

```
struct structure *a, *b;
init_structures(&a, &b, NULL);
```

Comment: `va_arg` is required to be a macro.

Answer (score 5):

§7.15.1.1 (The `va_arg` macro) of [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) requires:

> The parameter *type* shall be a type
>   name speciﬁed such that the type of a
>   pointer to an object that has the
>   speciﬁed type can be obtained simply
>   by postﬁxing a * to type.

That is why parentheses are not permitted here.

Other answers have explained why you need to pass in `struct structure **` and assign the malloc result to `*s`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put parens around the type in  `va_arg`. You don't need to. `va_arg` is a strange beast. Practically, it's a CPP macro that expands into some sort of per-compiler magic. If you look at the expansion of it with your compiler, you will see how your compiler does it. Whatever it is, it don't like parens.